# To 'chisel' some territory - what does it mean? (from the Godfather)

Tags: word-meaning

From the Godfather movie:

> Barzini's people chisel my territory and we do nothing about it. Soon
>   I'll have no place in Brooklyn to hang my hat.

The only meaning I've found for the word chisel is

> a tool with a flat metal blade used for cutting wood or stone

It also means doing some work with that tool. In the context it seems nonsensical to say the least, so I guess it's an idiomatic expression. I'd also guess that Barzini's people getting control in his ground, gradually pushing him out of his affairs there.

Comment: A *chiseler* (slang) is a cheat. To work with a chisel is to take small pieces  off the main piece, a little at a time. See *chisel* #2 here (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chisel)

Comment: @TRomano So that meaning of chisel is the same as to tear the pieces?

Comment: Not exactly, but somewhat similar to "tear off pieces". It means constantly removing small bits, thus making the territory smaller and smaller.

Comment: The word began as a figurative extension of the physical action of shaving off small pieces, that is, to cheat someone  in a manner not likely to be noticed. But it has lost specificity and can mean simply "to be unscrupulous in one's dealings."  I think it is used in the more specific meaning in the Godfather.   Barzini is "whittling away" at their Brooklyn business.

Comment: So it could be a _double entendre_ —referring both to cheating and to nibbling away the territory.

Comment: Maybe you give another example? It's still hard for me to understand the exact meaning.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQp_iQXq3h0Ah1iRiOPdRVhCZdHUrfXvF9ml_sI6HQAYJlOm8zc

Comment: In Brooklyn, Barzini is taking business away from the Corleone family, one small piece at a time. To use the word "chisel" to describe this activity is thus metaphorically accurate; but because of the association with the slang meaning of "chisel", it is also a way of describing Barzini as unscrupulous (in Coreleone's eyes) for not honoring the Corleone family's "claim" to Brooklyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *chisel* is indeed a tool used for cutting wood or stone. When used, it removes small pieces of the wooden or stone object, making that object smaller and smaller with each hit.

So here, *Barzini's people* are stealing small pieces of territory at a time, making the speaker's territory smaller and smaller.