# left to build on

Tags: sentence-meaning

From the Godfather movie:

> Clemenza: Don Corleone, You once said that the day would come Tessio
>   and me could form out own family. Till today I would never think about
>   it. I must ask your permission.
>
> Don: Michael is now the head of the family. If he gives you permission
>   then you have my blessing.
>
> Michael: After we make the move to Nevada, you can break of from the
>   Corleone family and go on your own.
>
> Clemenza: How long will it be?
>
> Michael: 6 months.
>
> Tessio: Forgive me, Godfather. But with you're gone me and Pete will
>   come under Barzini's thumb sooner or later.
>
> Clemenza: I hate that goddamn Barzini. **In six motnths' time there
>   will be nothing left to build on.**

I can't find more or less sensical meaning of the emphasized sentence. What he was going to build on? What could it mean in that context?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/build+on

Comment: nothing remaining on which (it will be possible) to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the context:

Clemenza and Tessio want to **build a new mafia family** after Don Corleone and Michael Corleone move to Nevada.

But the current **territory** is being [chiseled](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61588/to-chisel-some-territory-what-does-it-mean-from-the-godfather), meaning there is no - figuratively speaking - "ground" left to build on.

This passage in the book is using the common metaphor of building a house which needs land (ground) to be built on, meaning there is no base /foundation left to start something new.

Comment: So, after that 6 moths Barzini's people take over all their territory so they will be no place to build their families, right?

Comment: @DmitryBundin, right. In six moths the opponents *will have taken over*.

Comment: Got it, thank you. BTW, why fif you use future perfect in the __will have taken over__. Why didn't just future simple sound fine?

Comment: Because they have already started the process and in six moths the process will be already complete - otherwise they would take over at a certain point six months in the future. Like: On <date> <politician A, future president> will take over from <politician B, current president>.